# Ember.js: Define a custom RESTAdapter and RESTSerializer?

Tags: ember.js

In the file `/app/adapters/application.js`, I have the following code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000',
  namespace: 'api'
});

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr, method) {
    return Ember.String.decamelize(attr).toLowerCase();
  },
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

However this results in the following error:

`Duplicate default exports`.

How should I restructure my code so that they both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two default exports in a single module, there can be only one (this is part of the module specification). Also, the adapter and serializer should go in different modules. The adapter belongs in `/app/adapters/application.js` and the serializer belongs in `/app/serializers/application.js` (this is part of Ember CLI's module convention).